# Using async functions that borrow arguments in contexts where trait object is needed

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I've recently started playing with async streams in Rust, and I keep finding myself in situations where I want to use async functions in the implementation of a `Stream`. The async functions often come from libraries I don't control, but for the sake of example suppose they look like this:

```
async fn bar_str(s: &str) -> String {
    s.to_string()
}

async fn bar_string(s: String) -> String {
    s
}
```

Also to keep things simple suppose I'm just trying to use these functions to implement a trait like the following (no actual stream stuff involved):

```
use std::future::Future;

trait Foo {
    fn bar(self) -> Box<dyn Future<Output = String>>;
}
```

For the `String` case this just works as you'd expect:

```
impl Foo for String {
    fn bar(self) -> Box<dyn Future<Output = String>> {
        Box::new(bar_string(self))
    }
}
```

For the case where the async function borrows, it doesn't.

```
impl Foo for &str {
    fn bar(self) -> Box<Future<Output = String>> {
        Box::new(bar_str(self))
    }
}
```

This fails to compile:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter '_ in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> foo.rs:23:18
   |
23 |         Box::new(bar_str(self))
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
...
```

I can understand why this is a problem, and I understand that the `async fn` syntax provides special handling for borrowed arguments like this (although I don't know anything about how it's actually checked, desugared, etc.).

My question is about what the best thing is to do in these situations generally. Is there some way I can reproduce the magic `async fn` is doing in my non-`async fn` code? Should I just avoid borrowing in async functions (when I can, since that's often a decision I didn't make)? In the code I'm currently writing I'm happy to use experimental or not-necessarily-future-proof solutions if they make reading and writing this kind of thing nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is not so much in the `async` but in the `Box<dyn Trait>` thing. In fact it can be reproduced with a simple trait:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

trait Foo {
    fn foo(self) -> Box<dyn Debug>;
}

impl Foo for String {
    fn foo(self) -> Box<dyn Debug> {
        Box::new(self)
    }
}

impl Foo for &str {
    fn foo(self) -> Box<dyn Debug> {
        Box::new(self) // <--- Error here (line 15)
    }
}
```

The full error message is:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:15:18
   |
15 |         Box::new(self)
   |                  ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'_` as defined on the impl at 13:14...
  --> src/lib.rs:13:14
   |
13 | impl Foo for &str {
   |              ^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/lib.rs:15:18
   |
15 |         Box::new(self)
   |                  ^^^^
   = note: expected `&str`
              found `&str`
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/lib.rs:15:9
   |
15 |         Box::new(self)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::fmt::Debug + 'static)>`
              found `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::fmt::Debug>`
```

There is a nice hint about what is going on in the last two lines... what is this `Box<(dyn Debug + 'static)>` thing?

When you write `dyn Trait` there is actually an [implicit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes) `'static` constraint to the type that implements that trait, so these two are the same thing:

```
Box<dyn Debug>
Box<(dyn Debug + 'static)>
```

But that means that we can only box a value whose type is `'static`. And `&'a str` is not a static type, so it cannot be boxed that way.

The easy solution is, as usual, to clone, if at all possible. This compiles and it's not too ugly:

```
impl Foo for &str {
    fn foo(self) -> Box<dyn Debug> {
        Box::new(self.to_owned())
    }
}
```

Or if you only use static strings, then `&'static str` is actually static and you can write:

```
impl Foo for &'static str {
    fn foo(self) -> Box<dyn Debug> {
        Box::new(self)
    }
}
```

If you actually want or need to borrow, then the boxed dyn object has to be generic over *some* lifetime. You have to change the return type of your trait, something like this:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

trait Foo<'a> {
    fn foo(self) -> Box<dyn Debug + 'a>;
}

impl Foo<'static> for String {
    fn foo(self) -> Box<dyn Debug> {
        Box::new(self)
    }
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> for &'a str {
    fn foo(self) -> Box<dyn Debug + 'a> {
        Box::new(self)
    }
}
```

But beware now that `Box<dyn Debug + 'a>` is not a static type by itself, but the type itself has a lifetime of `'a`.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but I'm afraid I may have overminimized, and this minimizes a little further. I can't clone, for example, since I need to call functions (that I don't control) that require a reference. I'd also tried adding an explicit lifetime parameter and ran into problems, but I'll take a closer look at making that work.

Comment: @TravisBrown: Yes, `async` issues are often several problems layered one atop the other. Anyway your original code with the explicit lifetime [does work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a30ed217fec10757c75089c986fedb5e). Maybe if you can post a playground link that shows the new problems?

Comment: Just confirmed that threading through an explicit lifetime does work (in at least one of the places where I was running into this in real code)! I must have just given up on that too quickly. Thanks for the clarification.